# Apache Spark : How to deal with hierachical data

Tags: apache-spark

I'm quite new to spark. I would like to know if spark can handle a hierachy of data like a tree. (without using graphx)
let's say I have a tree represented in a flat file

- Key  Value
- A1   P1
- A1   P2
- P1   S1
- P1   S2
- P1   S3
- P2   S4
- S1   C1
- S1   C2

Is there a way to force Spark to reduce in the following order:

- S1 (C1+C2)
- P1 (S1+S2+S3) and P2 (S4)
- and then once P1 and P2 are reduced
- A1 (P1+P2)

If I use a "reduceByKey" the order is random.
Thanks for any hint

Comment: Please provide the reduceByKey approach that you have tried!

Answer (score 0):

You can write the code yourself to do this, but AFAIK you cannot do this via the API. The approach to do it, will vary depending on the use-case and the characteristics of graph(e.g. huge number of edges, intense computations, large nodes/data)

One approach to do this, assuming that the number of nodes is low is to process the graph level by level. In order to do that, you will need to extract the graph hierarchy information to a Broadcast variable and the apply a set of Unions and Filters until you've computed the top level nodes.

As @zero323 said, this might be a bit tricky if you are new to Spark, but in my use-cases it worked perfectly aggregating +80000 nodes with 100s GBs of underlying data.

The way to think about it is that each call to Spark aggregates one graph level. Hence, if the depth of your graph is high or you have billions of nodes this approach will not work.

Comment: Thanks. I see that it will be tricky as i deal with large trees (millions of nodes)